# Embedded YouTube videos without hidden controls until clicking on the video

Tags: youtube

I'd like to display embedded YouTube videos with the controls hidden by default, and when the user clicks on the video, controls appear. Just as the videos on [this page](http://www.chrisspooner.com/).

In Google documentation pages I found how to hide controls altogether, but not in this way. And using Firebug while visiting this page I can't see any options used in the iframe code that relates to controls.

So how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

for some reason the  embed code isn't allowing you to hide player controls anymore (it was working yesterday). The way I used to make it work again is to use the old embed code with the parameters to hide the controls when you click the video they show up but if you roll out they hide again here's the code:

```
<object width="560" height="310">
  <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/_-7K-z5zzOs?version=3&rel=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0"></param>
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/_-7K-z5zzOs?version=3&rel=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" width="560" height="310"></embed>
</object>
```

**UPDATE**
its back working fine here's the code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="240" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/_-7K-z5zzOs?autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "autohide" parameter worked for me:

```
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C4wPA6EKTJw?autohide=1" width="800" height="460" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```